# Can't verify my domain with Google Apps

Tags: dns, google-apps

I am trying to verify my domain with Google Apps to no success.

So far, I have tried 3 main methods of verification:

1. TXT (or CNAME) record.
2. Meta tag with verification code.
3. HTML file with verification code name and content.

My domain is http://michaelpumo.com

No matter which form of validation I follow, Google Apps says it cannot verify it. I am all out of ideas.

The HTML file on the server is here:
http://michaelpumo.com/google56f498ff499c68bc.html

The meta tag is viewable in the page source at the top in the head:

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="3scjFuAQJfrnce34RE6TkwF21NlAnWk7VUwXi86bRs8">
```

My DNS records look something like:

[image]

I have used dig, ping and other commands to verify DNS. I have also requested for Google to clear its DNS cache, as well as clear my own local caches etc. No luck.

Any pointers on something I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I hadn't done anything wrong with the setup. For some reason it just wasn't working. I got on the phone to Google and they fixed it up for me within a few minutes.

I would recommend getting on the phone if you have similar issues.